# Bind a progress bar to a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I have some code which pushes some code to a machine via telnet sessions.
During this time (around 30 sec) the GUI (tkinter) hangs, and it seems as if the program has crashed. To solve this issue I wanted to use a progress bar.  So, upon pressing the button "send" it opens up a new screen. So far so good.
Now, I want the progress bar to stop once the telnet script is done. So I've researched a bit, and I think I need to use (multi)thread. Once the telnetthread has done, the progressbarthread should stop, and I see the main screen again.

This is the script thusfar...

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk, HORIZONTAL
import time
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import threading



class main(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = Button(self, text='Run', command=self.pb)
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def pb(self):
        def real_pb():
            window = tk.Toplevel(root)
            window.progress = Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,  mode='indeterminate')
            window.progress.grid(row=1,column=0)
            window.progress.start()

            time.sleep(10)#to be changed to thread of telnet session//dummyscript

            window.progress.stop()
            window.progress.grid_forget()
            window.destroy()
            self.btn['state']='normal'

        self.btn['state']='disabled'
        threading.Thread(target=real_pb).start()

    def dummyscript():
        time.sleep(10)
        print("slept")

root = main()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I change the `time.sleep` to the length of the dummyscript?

Comment: You've explained what you're trying to do but haven't asked a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: added the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Tkinter does not support multithreading so all the code concerning the GUI should be in the main thread. So the toplevel and progressbar cannot be created in `real_pb()`.

What I would do to display the progressbar as long as the process is running is to use a `threading.Event` object that will be set when the process is finished. Inside Tkinter mainloop, I will regularly poll the Event to know whether the process is finished:

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk, HORIZONTAL, Toplevel
import time
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import threading


class Main(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = Button(self, text='Run', command=self.pb)
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.finished = threading.Event()  # event used to know if the process is finished

    def pb(self):

        def check_if_finished():
            if self.finished.is_set():
                # process is finished, destroy toplevel
                window.destroy()
                self.btn['state']='normal'
            else:
                self.after(1000, check_if_finished)

        window = Toplevel(root)
        window.progress = Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,  mode='indeterminate')
        window.progress.grid(row=1,column=0)
        window.progress.start()
        self.btn['state']='disabled'

        threading.Thread(target=self.dummyscript).start()
        self.after(1000, check_if_finished) # check every second if the process is finished

    def dummyscript(self):
        self.finished.clear()  # unset the event
        time.sleep(10)         # execute script
        print("slept")
        self.finished.set()    # set the event

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```